# how to retrieve the code coverage of the changed lines of code in a pull request?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

is there an api for retrieving the code coverage of the changed lines of code in a pull request?

looking at the docs for the azure devops api, pull requests does not include the code coverage for the changed lines of code, but then I wouldn't expect it to, because that's not part of git, is it?

the code coverage api doesn't seem to include anything about the coverage of changed lines of code.

any pointers much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can see code coverage only for changed files directly in Azure DevOps pull requests, see documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/codecoverage-for-pullrequests?view=azure-devops